# Centering a newcolumntype on a custom character

Tags: tables, tabularx, alignment

I received great help on this question:
[Table nesting with columnar widths based on uniform parent width, not uniform child width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458742/table-nesting-with-columnar-widths-based-on-uniform-parent-width-not-uniform-ch)

I'm looking to center columns on a character in mathmode.  I understand this is often conventionally done on [equals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4964/align-equals-sign-in-table) or [decimal points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/clarification-on-the-use-of-with-table-headings)

I have a newcolumntype defined like so:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
```

How would I modify this column type so that the contents of the column would center on `$=$` or `$\rightarrow$`?  To somehow incorporate something like `c@{$\rightarrow$}`?

I tried this:

```
\newcolumntype{C2}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X@{$\rightarrow$}}
```

But the result when I used it was

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (2.3333): `c' used.
```

Comment: Replace `\newcolumntype{C2}` by `\newcolumntype{A}` (or any other letter except `c`, `l`, `r`, `m`, `p`, `b`, `X` and `S`)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `dcolumn` package and a column such as `D{>}{\rightarrow}{-1}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}{D>{\;\rightarrow\;}{3.3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{XCX}
  xxx & 1 > 2 & hh\\
  x & 1 > 222 & hhhh\\
  xxx & 123 > 2 & hh\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does dcolumn work with tabularx?  I'm getting:

```! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.814 \end{tabularx}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me:
`! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \rightarrow 
`

Comment: @Mittenchops the code posted should work (there was an initial version before an edit that had \rightarrow in two places, the character in the data needs to be a character  not a command so I use `>` here to represent the arrow,. Works with tabularx, I will use tabularx instead of tabular in the example, look in a minute